# Как объединить ArrayList из разных классов?

Tags: java

У меня есть класс Company и 3 дочерних класса, которые наследуют методы из родительского класса, как получить 1 ArrayList со всеми значениями зарплат из разных классов

```
public class Company implements Employee {

    List<Double> salary = new ArrayList<>();

    public void getAllSalary() {
        List<Double> allSalary = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void hireAll(Integer num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            salary.add(getMonthSalary());
        }
    }

    public void hire() {
        salary.add(getMonthSalary());
    }

    public void getTopSalary() {

    }

    @Override
    public double getMonthSalary() {
        return 0;
    }
}


public class Operator extends Company implements Employee {

    @Override
    public double getMonthSalary() {
        return 30000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    }
}

public class Manager extends Company implements Employee {

    @Override
    public double getMonthSalary() {
        return 60000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 20000);
    }
}

public class TopManager extends Company implements Employee {

    @Override
    public double getMonthSalary() {
        return 100000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 50000);
    }

}
```

Comment: никогда не считайте деньги в double.

Comment: @Дмитрий, аргументируйте пожалуйста, почему не нужно этого делать.

Comment: @And потому что double - неточный типп данных. если в нем считать деньги , то при большом количестве рассчетов (например, в банковских системах) погрешность может быть очеть значительна. посему только long (разумеется, в центах, копейках и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
 public class CompanyService{
    public List<Double> getAllSalary(List<? extends Company> companies) {

        List<Double> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Company company : companies){
           res.add(company.getMonthSalary());
        }
        return res;
    }
 }
```

Comment: А зачем нужна эта строка ?  
long res = 0L

Comment: Почему-то не получается вывести список в основном main, просят ввести значение в скобку

Comment: Выложите последний вариант кода, или дайте ссылку на github

Comment: Такой страницы нет.

Comment: https://github.com/AlexSahkaaa/Company/tree/master

Comment: Я поправил сущности https://github.com/jlk191603/Company/tree/master/src/main/java/ru/alexsahka/company

Answer (score 0):

В общем , если я правильно понял задачу, это выглядит так

```
import java.util.List; import java.util.stream.Collectors;

interface Employee {

    long getMonthSalary();

    List<Long> getSalaries();

    static List<Long> getAllSalary(List<? extends Employee> companies) {
        return companies.stream()
                .flatMap(c->c.getSalaries().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
     }

import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public abstract class Company implements Employee {

    private final List<Long> SALARY;

    public Company() {
        this.SALARY = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Company hireAll(Integer num) {
        long salary = getMonthSalary();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) this.SALARY.add(salary);
        return this;
    }

    public Company hire() {
        return this.hireAll(1);
    }

    public long getTopSalary() {
        return SALARY.stream().mapToLong(v->v).max().orElse(0);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> getSalaries() {
        return SALARY;
    }
     }

public class Manager extends Company {

    @Override
    public long getMonthSalary() {
        return 60000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 20000);
    }
     }

public class Operator extends Company {

    @Override
    public long getMonthSalary() {
        return 30000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    }
     }

public class TopManager extends Company {

    @Override
    public long getMonthSalary() {
        return 100000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 50000);
    }
     }

import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        List<Employee> employies = new ArrayList<>();        
        employies.add(new Operator());
        employies.add(new Manager().hireAll(10).hireAll(5));
        employies.add(new TopManager().hire());    
        List<Long> allSalary = Employee.getAllSalary(employies);
        System.out.println(allSalary);        
    }
     }
```